# Safari dont go to fullscreen from iframe

Tags: safari, fullscreen

I'm using [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/) to open DOM elements in fullscreen mode, everything works as expected beside in Safari (using 6.0.2). Are there any known problems that prevents Safari from going into fullscreen mode?

Additional info, the side runs in an iframe, which should no problem as it has set the `allowFullScreen` attribute to true. But this seems to be the reason for the problem, running the iframe in a new window let the fullscreen stuff work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframe need to have the special `webkitAllowFullScreen` attribute for Safari to work:

Comment: Since Safari 7 you can just use the unprefixed `allowFullScreen`

Comment: and yet none of both works for me